# Extract string that contains only letters in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, c#-4.0

```
 string input = "5991 Duncan Road";
 var onlyLetters = new String(input.Where(Char.IsLetter).ToArray());
```

**Output: DuncanRoad**

But I am expecting output is **Duncan Road**. What need to change ?

Comment: Use regex `[a-zA-Z ]+` with global flag and then trim the string. Check [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aX1hF4/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the input like yours, you do not need a regex, just skip all non-letter symbols at the beginning with [`SkipWhile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549075%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Bypasses elements in a sequence as long as a specified condition is true and then returns the remaining elements.

C# code:

```
var input = "5991 Duncan Road";
var onlyLetters = new String(input.SkipWhile(p => !Char.IsLetter(p)).ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(onlyLetters);
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/WhSm1K)

A regx solution that will remove numbers that are not part of words and also adjoining whitespace:

```
var res = Regex.Replace(str, @"\s+(?<!\p{L})\d+(?!\p{L})|(?<!\p{L})\d+(?!\p{L})\s+", string.Empty);
```

Comment: If the input is `"5991 Duncan Road 34 ABC"` the output will be `Duncan Road 34 ABC`, which contains not only letters. Is this what you want?

Comment: Just in case there is need to remove `5991` and `34` with correct spacing, use [`\s+(?<!\p{L})\d+(?!\p{L})|(?<!\p{L})\d+(?!\p{L})\s+`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cs%2b(%3f%3c!%5cp%7bL%7d)%5cd%2b(%3f!%5cp%7bL%7d)%7c(%3f%3c!%5cp%7bL%7d)%5cd%2b(%3f!%5cp%7bL%7d)%5cs%2b&i=5991+Duncan+Road+34+4ABC&r=). C#: `var res = Regex.Replace(str, @"\s+(?<!\p{L})\d+(?!\p{L})|(?<!\p{L})\d+(?!\p{L})\s+", string.Empty);`

Comment: Note that you have accepted an answer that messes whitespaces in the resulting string and removes digits that are part of alphanumeric words. My regex above handles those cases more elegantly.

Comment: @stribizhev: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this lookaround based regex:

```
repl = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<![a-zA-Z])[^a-zA-Z]|[^a-zA-Z](?![a-zA-Z])", "");
//=> Duncan Road
```

- `(?<![a-zA-Z])[^a-zA-Z]` matches a non-letter that is not preceded by another letter.
- `|` is regex alternation
- `[^a-zA-Z](?![a-zA-Z])` matches a non-letter that is not followed by another letter.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zB2pC1/1)

Comment: string input = "5991 Duncan Road";
  Expected output: Duncan . How to get this output from regex.? - @Anu

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ Anu. in  "5991 Duncan Road De TB". here i need to get only 2nd item "Duncan" without using array. is it possible in regular exp?

Comment: Sorry to say this "Its returning the " Duncan Road  De TB "". @ Anu.

Comment: Sorry but I think you are either not understanding the regex or not implementing it correctly. Asking question and providing answers from comments is difficult also. Anyway if you're using other answer that is not using regex then why looking for a regex answer?

Comment: @Anu- Thank you. For this one  i like to use regular exp.!

Comment: I am sorry . I haven't notice that.

Answer (score 2):

You can still use LINQ filtering with `Char.IsLetter || Char.IsWhiteSpace`. To remove all leading and trailing whitespace chars you can call [`String.Trim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string input = "5991 Duncan Road";

string res = String.Join("", input.Where(c => Char.IsLetter(c) || Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)))
                   .Trim();

Console.WriteLine(res); // Duncan Road
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.   If I need only "Duncan" from the string (means only 2nd item). Is it possible to get using the LINQ filtering ?

Comment: @RajeshD - you can use `String.Split` and indexing, like `var secondWord = input.Split()[1];`

Comment: @Thanks w.b.. Thanks alot.